# Create a 'virtual' numpy array from scipy frequency matrix and array of values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have an *M* by *W* frequency matrix `doc_word_freqs` denoting the number of times word *w* appears in document *m* in a scipy CSR matrix. I also have a *W*-dimensional vector `z_scores` with some values associated with each word (in my particular case, the z-score of each word's log-odds ratio between two subsets of a corpus, but that is not germane to the problem).

I'd like to calculate some metric (in this case, the variance) over the set of z-scores for each document. That is, something like:

```
np.var(doc_z_scores, axis=1)
```

where `doc_z_scores` has *M* rows and each row contains a list of z-scores for each of the words in document *m*. Here's what I have now, but it's rather inelegant and very slow:

```
docs = [[]] * doc_word_freqs.shape[0] # Make a list of M empty lists

for m, w in zip(*doc_word_freqs.nonzero()):
    # For each non-zero index in doc_word_freqs, append the
    # the z-score of that word the appropriate number of times
    for _ in range(doc_word_freqs[m, w]):
        docs[m].append(word_z_scores[w])

# Calculate the variance of each of the resulting lists and return
return np.array([np.var(m) for m in docs])
```

Is there some way to do this without actually creating the arrays of variances (or whatever other measure it might be)?

Comment: I was able to optimize things by breaking down the variance calculation and only computing `abs(z_score - doc_mean)**2` once for each document-word pair (and only for pairs with non-zero frequency). That sped things up considerably, but I'm still curious to know if there's a way to do it that doesn't involve advance knowledge of the future operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question correctly. You could use matrix-vector multiplication:

```
weight = (doc_word_freqs @ np.ones_like(word_z_scores)).A.ravel()
mean = (doc_word_freqs @ word_z_scores).A.ravel() / weight
raw_2nd = (doc_word_freqs @ (word_z_scores**2)).A.ravel()
variance = raw_2nd / weight - mean**2
```

For "unbiased" variance use `-1` where appropriate.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, Paul.